# Is a function of bounded variation necessarily monotonic?

Tags: real-analysis

We know that a function of bounded variation can be expressed as a difference of two increasing function. I was just curious about this question.

Comment: Is your question does BV imply monotone? If so, it does not. $x\mapsto |x|$ is Lipschitz on $[-1,1]$ and hence BV there too.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider f(x)=sin(x). COnsider f(x)=cos(x).